# How do I design my class?

Tags: java, coding-style

I am trying to figure out how I should arrange my classes so that I can achieve a following.

So, ultimately I have a graph which takes nodes and edges.

And the idea is to run some graph algorithm based on these nodes and edges.

So, the basic unit Graph class takes are

```
private Node node
private Edge Edge
```

and you form a graph .. right

Now, here is the issue.

I have a special Edge say special Edge which implements the earlier Edge and has some more special properties of its own.

So I have a graph of type `Node, SpecialEdge`

Now, how do I use graph G which accepts Edge and not SpecialEdge??

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an interface Edge where subclasses like SpecialEdge would implement it. You may have many implementations of Edge and it will always work.

Also, since your Graph contains many nodes and many edges, you may consider using `List<Node>` and `List<Edge>` in your design.

Edit: According to Nick, you should use `Set<Node>` and `Set<Edge>` since the order is not an issue in this case.

Comment: Any reason why you'd use `List`s instead of `Set`s? The usual idea of a graph doesn't define any order to the edges or nodes, and doesn't admit repeated edges or nodes, so it seems to me that `Set` would model the collections better than `List`.

Answer (score 2):

You should create two different subclasses of Edge, namely BasicEdge and SpecialEdge.

A graph that should accept both should be Edge. If you only want one type, accept either BasicEdge or SpecialEdge.

Comment: But it looks like `Edge` and `SpecialEdge` are already hierarchically related.

Comment: @arshajii Edge is a catch-all class, or possibly even interface. Being  BasicEdge is a marker for being basic.

Comment: The original poster's question is too vague in that he's not describing in enough detail what is wrong with his current class hierarchy.